# I am new to LWC. I want to put condition on existing Account

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

My task is to go to Accounts Tab and click any of the record. If Rating field is set to Hot or I change the field value to hot, it should show alert message.
I have achieved it by creating and inserting new account.

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement, api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import LeadSource from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LeadSource';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import RATING_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Rating';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
export default class AccountHotField extends LightningElement {
    @track name = NAME_FIELD;
    @track  rating=RATING_FIELD;
 
    @track enablefield = false;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    accountInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues,
        {
            recordTypeId: '$accountInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
            fieldApiName: RATING_FIELD
        }
    )
    ratingValue;
    rec = {
        Name : this.name,
        Rating :this.rating
    }

    handleNameChange(event) {
        this.rec.Name = event.target.value;
        console.log("name1", this.rec.Name);
    }
    
    
    handleRatingChange(event) {
        this.rec.Rating = event.target.value;
       /* if ( this.rec.EmployeeNos == '' ){
            alert( this.rec.EmployeeNos )
            }*/
            if(this.rec.Rating != null && this.rec.Rating == 'Hot')
            [
                
                    alert("Your have selected rating Hot", this.rec.Rating )
                
            ]    
        
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Accounts Table" icon-name="standard: account" >
        <div class="slds-p-around_x-small">
            <lightning-input label="Name" value={rec.Name} onchange={handleNameChange}>test</lightning-input>
            
                <template if:true={ratingValue.data}>
                    <lightning-combobox name="progress" label="Rating" value={value}
                        options={ratingValue.data.values} onchange={handleRatingChange}>
                    </lightning-combobox>
                </template>
            
   
            <lightning-button label="Save"  onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
        </div>
        
    </lightning-card>

</template>
```

Comment: Why You are using LWC? this can be achieved by simple validation rule.

Comment: yes but i have to do it by LWC